# Facebook. How to get list of all users of my app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I've been googling before asking but all in vain unfortunately. Is the only possibility to have all facebook users of my app is maintaining my own database or maybe there's a simpler way provided by any Facebook API? Can anyone help me out? How do i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get a list of people using my facebook application](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1899473/get-a-list-of-people-using-my-facebook-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't provide a way to retrieve users who have your application installed. And you should store that information on your end to be able to track this.

You can only retrieve count of users who use your application from Application Insights (see answer to similar question: [How do I get all the users that have authorized my Facebook app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4579717/how-do-i-get-all-the-users-that-have-authorized-my-facebook-app))

Comment: As of 2014, this is not true.

Comment: @FractalBob, despite all the changes in the Facebook APIs it's still true and application doesn't have a way to list all their users via API.